# How to limit the value of one cell's value by another cell's value?

Tags: excel, vba, compare

I have a table full of numbers. I need a macro script, which will compare the target value with the score value. In case of the score value is higher than the target value, then change the target value to the score value.

Can somebody help me?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp1xQ.jpg)

I have tried to apply the following code on one cell, but it didn't work.

```
Sub check_value()
  If Cells(8, 23).Value < Cells(8, 24).Value Then
    Cells(8, 23).Value = Cells(8, 24).Value
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: But on your sheet both cells have the same value? Just for your understanding, currently you are comparing cell row 8, column 23 against cell row 8 column 24. These both have value 5.

Comment: `Target` and `Score` are on separate rows, and you're comparing columns... is that not an issue in itself?

Comment: @JvdV thanks buddy. I have mixed the rows with columns ;-)

Comment: Now, when I've fixed my issue, how can I apply this to all target cells?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site isn't a code writing service. Please take a moment to re-read the guidelines for asking questions here in the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: @Cyril You are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may help you:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, Row As Long, Target As Long, Score As Long, LastColumn As Long, Column As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For Column = 2 To LastColumn

            For Row = 2 To LastRow Step 2

                Target = .Cells(Row, Column).Value
                Score = .Cells(Row + 1, Column).Value

                If Score > Target Then
                    .Cells(Row, Column).Value = Score
                End If

            Next Row

        Next Column

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

F2 and F3 have a scenario where the Target < Score, so we can compare the values (similar to what you've got)

```
if cells(2,6).value < cells(3,6) then cells(2,6).value = cells(3,6).value
```

My only correction from your tested code is using rows to compare, rather than columns, which appears to be how each Skill is being assessed (e.g., Target for Skill 5 is 5 (F2), while the Score is 7 (F3)).

---

Note that you can use a loop to get through the whole data set by finding last column (lc) and last row (lr), such that:

```
For j = 2 to lc 'columns
    for i = 2 to lr step 2 'rows with a step of 2 so you can do sets of score/target
        'do stuff
    next i
next j
```